# PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file

Tags: c++, sun, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to compile a C++ application on SUN server using the compiler Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc Patch 124863-01. It seems that the Pro*C++ compiler is not able to identify some system header files like `vector`, `list`...

I am new to C++ and I am wondering if the compiler could not find the header file itself, or it cannot identify it since it was specified without `.h` extension.

I checked also the `pcscfg.cfg` configuration file (below) which should point to the system header files for pro*C compilation and it seems correct as well:

```
sys_include=(/usr/include)
ltype=short
```

---

```
PCC-W-02109, SQLCHECK=NONE is no longer supported.. using SYNTAX
Error at line 6, column 10 in file BillImageRef.pcpp
#include <vector>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 6, column 10 in file ./include/BillImageRef.hpp
#include <list>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
Error at line 7, column 10 in file ./include/BillImageRef.hpp
#include <map>
```

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using the C++ compiler (not the C one)? Did you try to compile with GCC?

Comment: yes I am using CC compiler for C++
I didnt try with GCC, but with CC it should work correct?

Comment: Actually i found all these system header files under /usr/sfw/include/c++/3.4.3/backward,I think including a sys_include=/usr/sfw/include can solve it

Answer (score 2):

In order to point to the exact location of standard library headers, you may need more `sys_include` definitions like:

```
sys_include=/ade/aime_rdbms_9819/oracle/precomp/public 
sys_include=/usr/include,/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i486-suse-linux/2.95.3/include 
sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/3.2.3/include
sys_include=/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux7/2.96/include
sys_include=/usr/include
```

as stated in the following link: [Precompiler Options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_10opt.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Visual Studio's variables or Environment variables, use sys_include instead of include. This was a major issue for me while compiling in VS 2013.