# PCC-S-02015, "unable to open include file"

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, oracle-pro-c

I am trying to compile a C++ program on UNIX using `CC: Sun C++ 5.11 SunOS_i386`. I created the following `Makefile`.

```
ORACLE_HOME=/app/ora/local/product/11.2.0.3/db_1
CC= CC -m64 -library=iostream

test.cpp : test.pc
    $(ORACLE_HOME)/bin/proc test.pc code=CPP sys_include=/usr/include cpp_suffix=cpp

test.o : test.cpp
    $(CC) -c test.cpp -DDEBUG -DSOLARIS -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/public

test.bin: test.o 
    $(CC) -o test.bin test.o  -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -lclntsh -lnsl -lsocket -lgen -ldl
```

When I executed the Makefile, I am getting the following error...

```
#include <iostream>
.........1
PCC-S-02015, unable to open include file
```

Is there anything I am missing? What else I can do?

Comment: Does you source code include Oracle ProC instructions? If yes, what part of the build chain is sending the error, `proc` or `CC`? If in doubt just execute manually the instruction from the makefile

Comment: @Rene: It looks like the error is from the Oracle ProC pre-compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I see the tag had been added.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131697/pcc-s-02015-unable-to-open-include-file?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your original source file is a Oracle Pro*C `.pc` file, the error means that Pro*C could not find your include file. If you have no FATAL error below caused by this, the PCC-S-02015 error is in fact a simple warning. The precompiler warns you that it has found an include directive that it could not process, so it leave it untouched in the generated `.cpp` file. In that case, it will be correctly processed by the next build step.

The problem if often that you use later a symbol defined in one of those include files (mainly a `typedef` or equivalent macro definition of a type) that leads to a fatal compilation error.

In that case you have to declare the include folders in the pcscfg.cfg file located at `$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin` or
include on the command line when invoking `proc`.

Ref: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2001/09/msg00273.html - it is about Debian but describes an equivalent problem.

Comment: Below are the content of pcscfg.cfg
sys_include=($ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public,/usr/include)
sys_include=(/net/14.96.53.37/devtools/i386/solstudio12.2/prod/include/CC/Cstd)

Comment: Yes as you mentioned, I can ignore those warnings. The binaries are getting generated. I executed each line in the make file and started including the directories to get it compiled.